# How can I use sed to alter the results of find and pass the results to cp?

Tags: macos, find, sed, solaris

In solaris, I'd like to copy all files found by the find command to a slightly different path.  The following script basically executes cp for each file found by find.  For example:

```
cp ./content/english/activity1_compressed.swf ./content/spanish/activity1_compressed.swf
cp ./content/english/activity2_compressed.swf ./content/spanish/activity2_compressed.swf
...

#!/bin/bash

# Read all file names into an array
FilesArray=($(find "." -name "*_compressed.swf"))

# Get length of an array
FilesIndex=${#FilesArray[@]}

# Copy each file from english to spanish folder
# Ex: cp ./english/activity_compressed.swf ./spanish/activity_compressed.swf
for (( i=0; i<${FilesIndex}; i++ ));
do
    source="${FilesArray[$i]}"

    # Replace "english" with "spanish" in path  
    destination="$(echo "${source}" | sed 's/english/spanish/')"

    cp "${source}" "${destination}"
done

exit 0;
```

It seems like a bit much and I wonder how to use sed in-line with the find and cp commands to achieve the same thing.  I would have hoped for something like the following, but apparently parentheses aren't acceptable method of changing order of operation:

```
find . -name *_compressed -exec cp {} (echo '{}' | sed 's/english/spanish/')
```

Comment: +1 for using `$()` instead of backticks.

Answer (score 7):

There are easier ways, but for portability sake we can use a bit of forking and backticks:

```
find . -name *_compressed -exec sh -c 'cp {} `echo {} | sed 's/english/spanish/'`' \;
```

Comment: Great! +1 The shell maniac! :D Can you give me some hints about the easier ways you was referring at? Maybe those ways will also accomplish better to that purpose.

Comment: I'm not sure on his exact environment, but if all of the files are only within 1 directory, he could `cd` there then just `cp *_compressed.swf ../spanish`

Comment: i was thinking the same but instead of 'cding' there he can just give it to 'cp' as the target directory.

Comment: When I make a test run on OS X, -exec sh -c 'cp {} ... works, but if I run on solaris... replacing cp with echo for safety.  Output is "{}"  I'm guessing that -exec sh -c doesn't work on solaris.

Comment: @John T: All of the files aren't in 1 directory.

Comment: @Michael that's why I said I wasn't sure on your environment. I made the answer with Linux and OSX in mind, solaris wasn't part of the question.

Comment: @John T: Added environment to question. :)  Thanks for introducing me to the -exec sh -c the other day.  I've found other good usage for it, regardless of the solaris work.

Comment: Try `-exec bash -c`

Comment: That doesn't work either.  I'm working on several tasks and trying different approaches I found that the following works on OSX and not on solaris, giving error about unexpected ( for the first parentheses: for FILE in ./content/english/reading/reading_comprehension/*_content_opt.swf; do echo mv $FILE $(echo $FILE | sed -e 's/_content_opt.swf/_compressed.swf/'); done

Old bash?

Comment: Or take a look at the extraordinary super-cow's powers of zsh

Answer (score 1):

I'd use the backtick:
you'll find more upon it [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_04.html) (backtick is at chapter 3.4.5).

Basically when you enclose a command between backticks the command itself will be substituted in his output.

Comment: $(COMMAND) and `COMMAND` result in the same output.